# How can I send ToggledEventArgs using MessagingCenter to a subscriber?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code right now:

```
CivToggledCmd = new Command<ToggledEventArgs>((e) => CivToggled(e));

public void CivToggled(ToggledEventArgs e)
   { App.DB.UpdateBoolSetting(SET.Civ, (bool)e.Value); }
```

I'm trying to convert it to use MessagingCenter but would like some advice on how I can pass the value of e over to the subscriber.  Here's what I have so far:

```
CivToggledCmd = new Command<ToggledEventArgs>((e) =>  
   MessagingCenter.Send<SettingsPageViewModel>(this, "CivToggled");

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SettingsPageViewModel>(this, "CivToggled",   (sender) => 
  { App.DB.UpdateBoolSetting(SET.Civ, (bool)e.Value); });
```

Can someone tell me how I can pass the event over to my Subscriber and how I can make it receive the event so it can update the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to send with an argument

```
MessagingCenter.Send<SettingsPageViewModel, ToggledEventArgs>(this, "CivToggled", e);
```

to subscribe with an argument

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SettingsPageViewModel, ToggledEventArgs>(this, "CivToggled", (s,e) => {
  App.DB.UpdateBoolSetting(SET.Civ, (bool)e.Value); 
});
```